# Tool to view/plan keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm curious if there are any tools available* that will help me generate visuals of keyboard shortcuts for the application I'm working on?

Being able to see on a picture of a keyboard what combinations are in use, the relationships between normal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations, and especially what combinations are NOT in use, would be wonderfully helpful.

Really, our team would just like to SEE the keyboard shortcuts without resorting to [Insert favorite picture editor]. I figured there'd be a quick and dirty tool to get this done, since programs have had keyboard shortcuts since the beginning of time.

I'm not expecting any integration with any IDE, although I'd love it if it existed. Just in case: Developing on Windows using VS 2008 & C#. If necessary, I'd do any necessary gruntwork (or write some quick code) to input the mappings myself.

Please forgive me if I am missing an obvious solution, but I've had no luck searching for such a tool myself, due to every application in existence having its own keyboard shortcuts, and all of those being listed on the web.

*Naturally, I'd prefer free/cheap, but it can't hurt to hear about any expensive options.

Comment: You might want to add which platform you're on.

Comment: This is fairly platform agnostic, as I'm not expecting integration with any other tools, just something self contained. BUT I am working on windows, and in case there is some magic plugin out there, developing in VS 2008 in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a spreadsheet.  One row for each key, with columns for <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Key, <kbd>Control</kbd> + Key, <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Key, etc.  Fill in the standard ones (cut, copy, paste, undo, save, etc.) and go from there.

Comment: He's looking for a tool that maps out the available shortcuts.

Comment: As in programmatically looking at his project file and identifying which ones he's already used?  If that's the case, why didn't he mention anything about the development environment he's using?  ;-)

Comment: is correct. I'm not expecting any kind of integration. I'm really just looking for something that will turn mappings into useful pictures. I'm willing to do the work of inputting the mappings myself.